# Custom 404 redirect for a luddite

Tags: custom-post-types, php, redirect, 404-error

I apologize in advance for the likely misuse of coding terminology. I am not very skilled when it comes to this.

In a separate website, I have links which when clicked bring up a .pdf of images corresponding to the feature's unique id: 
`/Images/{ID}.pdf` 
which results in something like `example.com/Images/1234.pdf` for feature 1234.
Now let's say someone clicks on the link for feature 1235, but it has no corresponding .pdf. The page currently redirects my generic 404 page I created in wordpress. How do I get it to direct to the specific page `example.com/Images/nopdf.pdf` for all non-existent pages under the subdomain /Images/? I appreciate in advance for the dumbed-down answers. 
Thanks,
Deacon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest customizing your 404 template, within your theme. That way you can add a conditional that only sends people to the "not found PDF" if they were trying to access a PDF. If they were trying to access any other document type, like a webpage, that doesn't exist, they will still see your regular 404 page.

To set this up:

If you are not already using a custom theme or a child theme, set one up. That way when you update your theme, you won't lose your customizations.

Edit, or create, a file called "404.php" in your (child or custom) theme's root directory. The contents should be something like this:

```
<?php
// check the requested URL
$requestUrl = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
// see if the URL contains the "Images" folder
preg_match('/Images/', $requestUrl, $matches);
// if the URL matches, it will be a non-empty array
if(count($matches) > 0) {
    wp_redirect('your-pdf-url-here');
// if the URL didn't match, use the normal 404 template
} else {
    // your normal theme 404 code, starting with get_header();
    // ...
    // ...
    // don't forget the closing } at the end of the file
}
?>
```

There is one other alternative if you don't want to edit theme files. You can create a plugin that does the same thing. Basically, you check if `is_404()`, then put in the same code - if the URL contains the Images folder, redirect to your pdf. You wouldn't need an "else" condition, you'd just let WP do its normal thing.

Comment: This is exactly the direction I want to go. Let me mess with it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: So I get redirected to my default 404 page with the warning: "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'l' in /home/slvgis5/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/404‌​.php on line 3" Line 3 reads: `preg_match('/images/Alamosa_PC/Images/', $requestUrl, $matches);`

Comment: In PHP regex the slash has to be escaped. So if you're trying to match that folder you'd actually type it like this: `preg_match('/\/images\/Alamosa_PC\/Images\//', $requestUrl, $matches);`

Comment: I love you. You are the greatest!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

[How to create custom 401, 403 and 500 error pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143031/how-to-create-custom-401-403-and-500-error-pages)

Please have a look at above answer and see how it is done. In short, you need to direct the current 404 page to `example.com/Images/nopdf.pdf` by putting this in your `.htaccess` file.

`ErrorDocument 404 example.com/Images/nopdf.pdf`

I am not even sure if serving up a PDF is a good idea as an error document. Make a short PHP document, that, if must be, has the PDF inside. Also keep in mind that this file will be loaded whenever there is a 404 error on your site, not just when an image cannot be found.